# Is it possible to distribute in-house apps built with the beta SDK using the iOS Developer Enterprise Program?

Tags: ios, provisioning, ios-provisioning

When using the "in-house" distribution method of the iOS Developer Enterprise Program, is it possible to build and install apps created with a beta (e.g. iOS 8) SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and that is what beta meant to be.

> New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with release versions of Xcode 5. Do not submit apps built with beta software, as beta versions are for **development and testing only**.

so iOS 8 beta SDK is for development and testing purpose. Without installing the app in device we cant test and AFAIK enterprise distribution method is not restricting you from installing apps.

Comment: Can confirm. After not finding any definitive documentation anywhere we bit the bullet, got the $300 enterprise program set up, and it does in fact allow us to distribute in-house applications built with the beta SDK.